# Node.js native modules build cache

Tags: node.js, npm, node-native-addon

Our project is quite big and compiling native addon dependencies on `npm ci` or clean `npm install` takes several minutes.

Is there any way to cache and re-use the built native addons except of saving `node_modules` as a whole?